# how to add confidence interval as coloured area to a boxplot of predicted values in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, confidence-interval

This is my data frame with predicted probabilities `Pred` from a bootstrapping process after construction of a model:

```
require(ggplot2)

Position <- rep(c("B", "A", "Stg", "Str"),3)

Week <- c(rep("1",4), rep("2",4), rep("3",4))

LC <- c(1.09E-02,1.40E-02,1.20E-02,2.86E-02,1.27E-05,1.26E-07,
        5.47E-02,1.34E-01,1.21E-02,8.51E-03,2.27E-02,2.61E-02)

Pred <- c(0.057243157,0.044744656,0.068085039,0.120633045,
          0.002791358,0.005735141,0.230200726,0.38286196,
          0.044698511,0.042201468,0.120200443,0.125982336) 

UC <- c(3.06E-02,3.82E-02,4.05E-02,7.50E-02,2.86E-03,
        1.94E-05,1.59E-01,2.83E-01,2.83E-02,2.91E-02,
        7.35E-02,7.59E-02)

df <- data.frame(Position, Week, LC, Pred, UC)
```

`Position` and `Week` are factors the rest is numeric.
I want to show `Position` on the x-axis and `Pred` on the y-axis in a boxplot. `LC`and `UC`are lower and upper limit of the confidence interval. My aim is to display the limits as coloured area in the background like in this example with this code

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Week, y = Pred, fill = Position)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = LC, ymax = UC, fill = Position), alpha = .15) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(colour = Position), size = 2) +
  ylim(c(0, 0.7))
```

Boxplot with coloured background for upper and lower CI limits:

[image: img1]

What i tried is

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Position, y = Pred, fill = Position)) +  
  geom_ribbon(data=pred,aes(ymin = LC, ymax = UC, fill = Position), 
              alpha = .15) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(colour = Position), size = 2, colour="black") +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom = "point", size = 1.5) + theme_bw()
```

But there is no colour in the background. Boxplot for Pred only without any background colour:

[image: img2]

I would appreciate any advice!

Comment: I believe what may be happening is that the boxplot is covering the ribbon (I assume that is what you mean by background).  Try reversing the order of geom_boxplot() and geom_ribbon() to see if my instinct is correct.  It would really help answerers if you would provide a very small data frame that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Boxplots were designed to display data where raw values were too numerous to be displayed as raw values. Assuming you only have 12-ish points, you might want to stick to more conventional methods of displaying this few points.

Comment: @Elin Thanks for your answer. But there is still no ribbon. I provided the data I have as data frame `df` at the beginning of my question.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik The boxplot is my professor's choice.

Comment: Since you only have the upper and lower limit, you should be using `geom_errorbar()`. `geom_boxplot()` requires other points like upper and lower quartile.

Comment: I'm confused by the goal. `Week` is discrete, but the ribbons imply a continuous trend, and I don't understand how to read them in the context of boxplots. Could you instead just use error bars or some type of point marking to show your upper and lower limits?

Comment: Yes I suspect that you may be misunderstanding the question and that's making it more complicated.

Comment: I understand it may not be your decision, which is why I do not talk statistics to (non-stats) professors anymore. They are just too set in their wrong ways about which I have nothing nice to say.